# Git - Push new commit and ignore uncommitted changes

Tags: windows, git, github, egit

I'm working with an Android app from a repo on Github. I've cloned the repo and I've made a change to one of the views, I've committed the change in Eclipse using the Egit plugin.

I now need to 'push' (I beleive) that change up to the Github repository.

I'm on Windows so thought I would give the new Windows Client a try - however this won't let me push the single commit without first dealing with all changes it has detected. As the repo is an Android app when I run the app to debug locally or on my device it creates lots of new classes and other such fluff so I'm unable to 'sync'. However I don't want to commit these files, just the single file I've committed.

Does this mean I need to turn to the command line to push the single file back up to Github?

Answer (score 2):

```
git add "<follow name>"
git commit -m "commit this file"
git push origin master
```

This will push the one file remotely.  You can also use .gitignore to tell git to ignore files you don't want to commit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what I'm looking for:

```
git push origin <thelonghash>:master
```